# How do I use an image as a link in Next.Js

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js

Does anyone know how I can use an image as a link in Next.Js. I have an image of the Instagram logo that I want to link to my Instagram page. When the user clicks on it it opens a new tab and sends the user to my Instagram page.

Any help would be appreciated

I have no Idea where to start. The Next.js docs dont describe how to link an image

Answer (score 1):

Just use a anchor tag and a image tag

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

```
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e7/Instagram_logo_2016.svg/264px-Instagram_logo_2016.svg.png" />
    </a>
```

Demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-forked-i66kox?file=/index.js

Answer (score 1):

In nextjs 13 you can use the Image tag inside the Link tag like this:
Place the insta Logo image where it suits you best or link to an external image.

```
import instaLogo from '@public/instaLogo.svg'
import Image from 'next/image'
import Link from 'next/link'

<Link href={'https://www.instagram.com/'}>
  <Image src={instaLogo} alt="My Insta" width={150} height={150} />
</Link>
```